# Difference between ArrayList and Array of object

Tags: java

I am not able to make the difference between ArrayList and Array of objects in java. I am just a beginner. Also I am not able to understand that why Array is sorted by Arrays.sort and ArrayList is sorted by Collections.sort if both are array only.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=arraylist+vs+array+java

Comment: Hey Parth, definitely check out those links provided. There are several types of arrays, and they use different notions of natural ordering in sort.

Comment: why they use different object for sorting

Comment: As far as Java's concerned, they're nothing like the same type.  `ArrayList` has an array in its implementation, but as far as Java's concerned that's the only overlap.

Comment: Also i want to know that Collections is an object or interface?

Comment: `Collections` is a class that can't be instantiated, so, neither.  `Collection` is an interface.

Comment: does it mean that it is  final class

Comment: @ParthPatel No, it just has a private constructor.

Comment: when i see in javadoc, i find that there is no constructor. then why you are telling that it has private constructor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is arrays have a set size you define where as an arraylist has infinite size.  You'll learn a lot about them from the api

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html